# pyinstallerを使用してpythonのexeファイルを作成する時、２度目の生成処理が失敗することがある

Tags: python, python3, pyinstaller

Anaconda Promptから「pyinstaller 【.pyファイルのフルパス】 --onefile」の命令でexeファイルの作成ができるにはできるのですが、exeファイル作成完了後に再度同じ命令を行った場合に確立でexe作成を中断してしまうことがあります。

.pyファイルのディレクトリに出現するbuildフォルダなどの処理時に生成されるファイル・ディレクトリをすべて削除すれば必ず出力成功するので別に困る事は無いのですが、毎回削除しなければならないのがpythonの基本ルールとなる認識で良いのでしょうか？

3.6/3.7/3.8どれでも発生するのでおそらく共通で発生するんじゃないかという認識です。

cubickさんに質問された内容を含む追記事項を書きます。
■１
exeを開いていない状態で再度生成命令を使用した際に上書きy/nの確認画面が表示されました。
YESを入力し、完了ログが表示されました。
ファイルの状況を確認するとdistフォルダ内のデータは再生成された時刻表示となっています。
しかし、Buildフォルダ内のアイテムの生成時刻は「COLLECT-00.toc」というファイルが再生成されただけで他のファイルの上書きは行われませんでした。

■２
再度別条件で実験
exeファイルをリネームし、同名ファイルが存在しない状態にしてみました。
exeファイルが再生されました。
他に
「EXE-00.toc」
「COLLECT-00.toc」
の２件のファイルが再生成されたようです。

▼
というところまで確認し、１点私の間違いの可能性を感じています。
.pyファイルから生成する一連の処理について、exeが格納されているディレクトリをbuildフォルダ側と認識しておりました。
上記の一切の記述はbuild側のディレクトリ内の説明になります。

どうやらdistフォルダ内にも全く同じファイルサイズで生成されているようなのですが、もしかしてdist側が正でbuildフォルダ内のexeは誤でしょうか？

とは言いつつも、distフォルダ内のexeもやはり上書きされず、distフォルダ側で上書きされたのは「●●●●●.exe.manifest」（●●●●●は元となった.pyファイル名）のみ上書きされているようです。

▼生成ログをいかに添付しておきます。基本的に再生成した際のログは以下共通の内容です。

```
(base) ディレクトリパス>pyinstaller ディレクトリパス\●●●●●.py --exclude pandas --exclude numpy
2796 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
2796 INFO: Python: 3.8.8 (conda)
2796 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2796 INFO: wrote ディレクトリパス\●●●●●.spec
2796 INFO: UPX is not available.
2796 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['ディレクトリパス',
 'ディレクトリパス']
4156 INFO: checking Analysis
4797 INFO: checking PYZ
4953 INFO: checking PKG
4953 INFO: Bootloader ディレクトリパス\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
4953 INFO: checking EXE
4968 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "ディレクトリパス\dist\●●●●●" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
On your own risk, you can use the option `--noconfirm` to get rid of this question.
9609 INFO: Removing dir ディレクトリパス\dist\●●●●●
12672 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
37361 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: 失敗する時に何かしらエラーメッセージのようなものは表示されていませんか？ / あくまで予想ですが、一度目に作成した exe を動作確認のために実行していたりしてビルド結果のファイルがロックされたりしていませんか？

Comment: 試してみました。今回初めて「The output directory "ファイルディレクトリパス" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)」ファイルの上書き確認が出現しました。とりあえずYESし、ログとしてはdistフォルダの中身がすべて再生成したよ。というログが出て完了扱いになりました。しかしexeファイルの最終保存時刻が更新されていない所を見るとエラーログ無しで未精製になっているように思います。また、exeファイルは開いていない状態を確認しております。

Comment: 追記：本件質問する前にライブラリのアップデート処理を行ってしまったため、質問内容を完全再現することができそうになさそうです。ですが、前述のy/nが表示された以外にアップデート前後で変わった挙動は無く、exeファイルが生成されない挙動自体は発生しています。

Comment: 2回目以降を実行する際、元になる Python のコードに変更はありますか？ (書き換える必要が無いから中断されている可能性もあります)

Comment: 言われてみれば確かにファイルの中身自体更新していない状態で再生成をしてます。次の２通りの更新を行ってみました。１．defで適当に関数を宣言してみる→exeは再生成されました。２．print('aaaa')を１行挿入→exe再生成されました。■ということはpyinstaller でexeを作成する処理を行う場合、exeの生成前後でソースコードに変更がないとスキップ処理が含まれてしまう。ということだと思います。生成に時間がかかる事を考慮すると便利な機能ですね。おそらく解決です。ありがとうございます。